# Запятая перед "по правде", смысловая (в конце абзаца)

Tags: пунктуация

> Роль Арбенина исполнял Александр Феклистов. На мой взгляд, это была не
>   только его безусловная актёрская удача, но и вообще лучшее из
>   увиденных мною исполнений этой роли. Образ бесконечно влюблённого
>   ревнивца, его боль, его безумие были созданы столь убедительно, что я
>   нередко отвлекалась во время спектакля и как зачарованная наблюдала за
>   теми душевными бурями, которые охватывали моего партнёра. И даже
>   иногда боялась его, по правде.

Даю такой большой фрагмент, чтобы было понятно: действуют второкурсница и мэтр.

Оправдайте, как можете, влепленную МНОЙ запятую... Не то застрелюся.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И **даже иногда боялась его, по правде** (говоря).

Обособленное вводное слово в конце предложения.

Сравнить: И даже иногда по правде  (= действительно) боялась его.